# how long does it take to transfer funds from India to uae through bank transfer?

Tags: india, transfer

I want around 6lac rupees transferred from a regular savings bank account in india to my account in UAE, how long will it take?  and can i tranfer this amount through western union?

Answer (score 1):

Normal Banking channels would take around 2-5 days provided that all the paperwork is in good order.